# Generate a transaction report with all the database tables in Unicentapos

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am trying to generate report in [unicentaopos4.2.2](/questions/tagged/unicentaopos4.2.2). The report is created in Jasper but there is a corresponding bs file. There is only one SQL query and for my report I need multiple query in the jrxml file.

This is the `sales_extendedcashregisterlog.bs` file that have only one SQL query with the `report.setSentence()`.

```
report = new com.openbravo.pos.reports.PanelReportBean();

report.setTitleKey("Menu.ExtendedCashRegisterLog");
report.setReport("/com/openbravo/reports/sales_extendedcashregisterlog");
report.setResourceBundle("com/openbravo/reports   /sales_extendedcashregisterlog_messages");

 report.setSentence("SELECT " +
    "tickets.TICKETID AS TICKET_NO, " +
    "receipts.DATENEW AS TICKET_DATE, " +
    "people.NAME AS PERSON, " +
    "payments.PAYMENT AS PAYMENT, " +
    "payments.NOTES, " +
    "payments.TOTAL AS MONEY, " +
    "payments.TENDERED " +
"FROM ((tickets tickets " +
    "LEFT OUTER JOIN people people ON (tickets.PERSON = people.ID)) " +
    "RIGHT OUTER JOIN receipts receipts ON (receipts.ID = tickets.ID)) " +
    "LEFT OUTER JOIN payments payments ON (receipts.ID = payments.RECEIPT) " +
"WHERE ?(QBF_FILTER) " +
    "ORDER BY TICKET_DATE ASC");

     report.addParameter("receipts.DATENEW");
     report.addParameter("receipts.DATENEW");

      paramdates = new com.openbravo.pos.reports.JParamsDatesInterval();

     paramdates.setStartDate(com.openbravo.beans.DateUtils.getToday());
     // JG - 8 Jan 14        paramdates.setEndDate(com.openbravo.beans.DateUtils.getToday());
    paramdates.setEndDate(com.openbravo.beans.DateUtils.getTodayMinutes());

      report.addQBFFilter(paramdates);

     report.addField("TICKET_NO", com.openbravo.data.loader.Datas.STRING);
      report.addField("TICKET_DATE", com.openbravo.data.loader.Datas.TIMESTAMP);
      report.addField("PERSON", com.openbravo.data.loader.Datas.STRING);
      report.addField("PAYMENT", com.openbravo.data.loader.Datas.STRING);
      report.addField("NOTES", com.openbravo.data.loader.Datas.STRING);
      report.addField("MONEY", com.openbravo.data.loader.Datas.DOUBLE);
       report.addField("TENDERED", com.openbravo.data.loader.Datas.DOUBLE);
      return report;
```

Now we have a jrxml file. I can edit this file using pallet feature but the thing is the sql query that give me the fields so that I can use them. here is the query of the jrxml file that it already have.

```
queryString>
    <![CDATA[SELECT 
 tickets.TICKETID AS TICKET_NO,
 receipts.DATENEW AS TICKET_DATE,
 payments.TOTAL AS MONEY,
 people.NAME AS PERSON,
 payments.PAYMENT AS PAYMENT
 FROM receipts
 LEFT JOIN tickets ON receipts.ID = tickets.ID
 LEFT JOIN payments ON receipts.ID = payments.RECEIPT
 LEFT JOIN people ON tickets.PERSON = PERSON.ID
 ORDER BY tickets.TICKETID]]>
 </queryString>
 <field name="TICKET_NO" class="java.lang.String"/>
 <field name="TICKET_DATE" class="java.util.Date"/>
 <field name="PERSON" class="java.lang.String"/>
 <field name="PAYMENT" class="java.lang.String"/>
 <field name="NOTES" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="MONEY" class="java.lang.Double"/>
<field name="TENDERED" class="java.lang.Double"/>
```

the fields are already inside. Now I want to add more than one sql query, so how exactly I can do it.

Basically I am trying to generate a transaction log in unicentaopos with all the needed data.